# Finding Partial Text In Full Row

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to search an entire row for a string that contains "PROFILE". It will always be capitalized, but the format will be, for example "[9]PROFILE001".

Some extra information: I have used the Find command to locate the row that I am searching in for the string. It has its own variable that I am trying to incorporate into the range I am using.

I have searched multiple partial string articles on here, and have not been able to implement it into my code. I have tried using the Like command and the IntStr command to no avail. I believe my issue may be with how im referencing the search range or how i am searching.

Here is a snippet of my current code:

```
'finding item name row
Set FindRow3 = Range("A1:A100").Find("Item Name", LookIn:=xlValues)
itemnamerow = FindRow3.Row
'The section above is working as intended

'searching for the word profile, the section below is the one I am having issues with
Range("B8:Z100").Style = "Normal"
If ActiveSheet.Range("B" & itemnamerow & ":Z" & itemnamerow) Like "*PROFILE" Then
    Range("C1").Value = "it worked"
End If
```

I am currently experiencing a run time error 13, type mismatch in the "If ActiveSheet..." line. I have not been able to get the correct index to make this correct.

I am trying to use that if the partial string is found, I want do something.

TIA

Comment: You're returning the `Value` implicitly in `ActiveSheet.Range("B" & itemnamerow & ":Z" & itemnamerow)`.  You need to make sure it can be cast to a `String` (or use the `.Text` instead).  You also need to test to see if `FindRow3 Is Nothing`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be `Like "*PROFILE*"` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the `Find` method, with `MatchCase` and `LookIn` arguments set. And probably `LookAt` for to ensure it checks actual values and not formula syntax.

```
Dim profileFound as Range
Set profileFound = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & itemnamerow & ":Z" & itemnamerow).Find("PROFILE",lookIn:=xlValues,MatchCase:=True,lookAt:=xlPart)

If Not profileFound is nothing Then
    debug.print profileFound.Value
    Range("C1").Value = "it worked"
else
    debug.print "no profile found"
End If
```

The reason your original code is failing is because Excel will not allow you to evaluate a multi-cell range against a single value. You could loop through each cell in the range and check each cell individually, but since `Find` is available, that is superfluous.

Comment: I should also mention that I am trying to check if it has "PROFILE" in it so I can use it to do something if so. In the code you posted, does it return a value for finding it etc. or how does it determine if its found.

Comment: @A.Jones - if "PROFILE" is found, then `profileFound` will be the range object (cell) where it was first found. If not found `profileFound` will be `Nothing`

Comment: This is kind of a side question. Now that it found it profileFound returns the string of what it found, is there a way to also determine what column so i can hide the data so it does not show up?

Comment: Thanks again! The hide didn't work like i wanted so I had to modify my code to fit in the if loop above so that I could use the column.delete if the profile was found.

Answer (score 3):

You don't provide enough parameters for the Range.Find operation. Switch to the worksheet's Match to locate *Item name* then again as a wildcard search to locate *profile*.

```
dim m as variant, n as variant

m = application.match("Item Name", range("A1:A100"), 0)

If not iserror(m) then

    n = application.match("*profile*", cells(m, "B").resize(1, 25), 0)

    If not iserror(n) then

        Range("C1").Value = "it worked " & cells(m, n+1).value

    end if

end if
```

Comment: The "Item name" search is running fine without any issues. It is just when I go to search for the partial string.

Comment: It may work now but there is no guarantee that it will continue to work. If someone changes the options of a Find on the worksheet your Range.Find inherits those changes. If you insist on using Find then provide enough options that it couldn't be wrong. Besides, Match is just as fast and you don't have to memorize a dozen optional arguments.

Comment: I will also try this in the near future, but I have not seen that syntax before so it is unfamiliar with me. I started learning VBA 2 days ago so I am fairly new to this, my only prior experience is 2+ years of MatLab.